# Python: fastest way to re.findall twice?

Tags: python, regex

I like regular expressions. I often find myself using multiple regex statements to narrow in on the value I need when trying to get a substring from a large block of text.

So far, my approach has been the following:

1. Use `resultOfRegex1 = re.findall(firstRegex, myString)` for my first regex
2. Check to see that `resultOfRegex1[0]` exists
3. Use `resultOfRegex2 = re.findall(secondRegex, resultOfRegex1[0])` for
   my second regex
4. Check to see that `resultOfRegex2[0]` exists, and print that value

But I feel like this is much more verbose and costly than it has to be. Is there an easier/faster way to match one regex and then match another regex based on the result of the first?

Comment: Use `re.search` to find the first value. Then use `re.findall`.

Comment: It depends what you are searching, what is your pattern and what is your string. There is no general answer. Using `re.findall` if you only need the first result is indeed useless.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew while `re.search` is less expensive, it is also more limited than `re.findall`, meaning using it instead of `re.findall` could actually require a third or additional regexes than just using `re.findall` twice. It's a valid suggestion, but it depends on the context with which it is used

Comment: @SlickRick: Could you clarify what you mean by "limited"? Please provide a real life example.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte you make a valid point about using `re.findall` for only getting the first result. I tend to use `re.findall` instead of `re.search` because I think it's easier to use the length and indexes of an array than to deal with all that group stuff

Comment: Show an example and your patterns.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew imagine you're parsing a csv file with regexes instead of being sane and using a framework. You're dealing with the row `"datafromcol1","datafromcol2","datafromcol3","datafromcol4"`. Say you want `datafromcol3`. Given `regex1 = '.*,.*,.*,'`, using re.search would leave you with `"datafromcol1","datafromcol2","datafromcol3",`. Say datafromcol1 is a 4 digit integer, datafromcol2 and 3 are strings with no digits. You can't isolate col2 from col3 by their contents, so say `regex2 = '\d{4},.*,',` and use that to get `"datafromcol3"`. Then use a third regex to get rid of quotes

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's a really contrived and awful example (I mean, you could just use `str.strip()` to remove quotes. But basically it comes back to what Casimiret is saying, it depends on the application. re.search is not always the best first step

Comment: There is no point in using `re.findall` if you need the first match. `re.search` is meant to do it.

Comment: When you say first match, do you mean the match from the first regex. Or are you saying that a first match is the 0th result from any given regex? I agree if you are using the latter definition. I disagree with you on the former

Comment: Aha! Nevermind, you're absolutely correct. I had `re.search` and `re.match` confused. Yes. When performing a series of regexes to isolate the first occurrence of a substring, `re.search` is always cheaper than `re.findall`. But `re.match` is not necessarily cheaper or more expensive than `re.search` for the first expression in a chain of regexes, as using `re.match` may necessitate additional regexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of groups is to allow extraction of subgroups from an overall match.

For example, instead two searches done the following fashion:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'The winning team scored 15 points and used only 2 timeouts'
>>> score_clause = re.search(r'scored \d+ point', s).group(0)
>>> re.search(r'\d+', score_clause).group(0)
'15'
```

Do a single search with a sub-group:

```
>>> re.search(r'scored (\d+) point', s).group(1)
'15'
```

One other thought: if you want to make decisions about whether to continue a findall-style search based on the first match, a reasonable choice would be to use [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.finditer) and extract values as needed:

```
>>> game_results = '''\
10 point victory:  1 in first period, 6 in second period, 3 in third period.
5 point victory:  0 in first period, 5 in second period, 0 in third period.
12 point victory:  5 in first period, 3 in second period, 4 in third period.
7 point victory:  3 in first period, 0 in second period, 4 in third period.
'''.splitlines()
>>> # Show period-by-period scores for games won by 8 or more points
>>> for game_result in game_results:
        it = re.finditer(r'\d+', game_result)
        if int(next(it).group(0)) >= 8:
            print 'Big win:', [int(mo.group(0)) for mo in it]

Big win: [1, 6, 3]
Big win: [5, 3, 4]
```